# como soluciono este error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object "

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ferias-master\ferias.php on line 84

```
    <?php
                        $rsFeriasMarcada = 
                        mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tab_ferias WHERE num_id_colaborador = $ferias->id_colaborador");

                        $feriasMarcada = mysqli_fetch_object($rsFeriasMarcada);

   linea 84---->        if ($feriasMarcada->num_id_colaborador == 0) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="marcar-ferias.php?id=<?php echo $ferias->id_colaborador; ?>">Marcar</a>
                        <?php
                        } else {                        
                            $dataFeriasMarcada = strtotime($feriasMarcada->dt_fim_ferias);
                            $dataAtual = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));                      
                            if ($dataFeriasMarcada < $dataAtual) {

                            mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE tab_colaborador SET dt_ultferias_inicio = '$feriasMarcada->dt_inicio_ferias', dt_ultferias_fim = '$feriasMarcada->dt_fim_ferias' WHERE id_colaborador = $feriasMarcada->num_id_colaborador");
                            mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM tab_ferias WHERE num_id_colaborador = $ferias->id_colaborador");
                            }

                            echo DataBr($feriasMarcada->dt_inicio_ferias) . " &agrave; " . DataBr($feriasMarcada->dt_fim_ferias) . " <a href='ferias.php?deletarFerias=" . $ferias->id_colaborador . "'><img src='img/ico_deletar.png' width='9' height='9' /></a>";
                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: Al parecer `$feriasMarcada = mysqli_fetch_object($rsFeriasMarcada);` no te está devolviendo un objeto válido. Debido quizá a que la conexión a la bd no funciona, a que no devuelve datos, etc. Haz un `var_dump($feriasMarcada);`  para depurar lo que estás obteniendo en esa variable y si tiene una propiedad llamada `num_id_colaborador`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si la consulta no obtiene resultados devuelve un null:

Valores devueltos [mysqli_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php):

> Devuelve un objeto con las propiedades de cadena que corresponden a la
>   fila obtenida **o NULL si no hay más filas en el conjunto de resultados**.

Antes de entrar en el if, podrías hacer una comprobación como:

```
if(!is_null($feriasMarcada )){...}
```

Comment: Te corregi la respuesta, aun que estas en lo correcto el motivo que pudiste no es realmente el que querias. convertir campos null de mysql a null de php no era el motivo, jeje

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda lo pude solucionar